# How to update the blocks db-table correctly

Tags: 6, blocks, updating

I wrote a module that comes with a default_view (a block view). The corresponding block is not automatically listed inside the blocks db-table, even after a cache clearing, but it is shown after I visit `admin/build/block`. My problem is that I have a `hook_update_N()`, which is going to update the blocks table (the configuration of this specific block); if it's not there, it can't be updated.

When I use [_block_rehash('MYTHEME')](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.module/function/_block_rehash/6) the table is updated, not only for MYTHEME (ZEN-subtheme) but also for the Minelli theme. Is there another way of "updating" the blocks-table? What exactly is going on, when `admin/build/block` is visited?

**Edit**: I just noticed that Pro Drupal Devel (2. Ed.) states, at page 218, to use a `Insert INTO` query and do it "by hand." I think thats what I'm going to do now.

Answer (score 1):

Use `INSERT INTO`. I've spent hours and hours using block_rehash and variants to no effect.